# I am having issues with a syntax error in PostgreSQL. I am trying to add a query and it is giving me an error

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, syntax-error

I am taking a Data Analysis Course on Udemy. I am using PostgreSQL. On one of my exercises, I tried to add a column of data and recieved a Syntax Error Message. Here is a screen shot of my code:

[image: PostgreSQL]

can someone help with this?

Comment: I doubt it.  The image is quite unreadable.  If you included the query and error message as *text*, there would be some hope.

Comment: Sorry about that. I will move on from the course. Thank You

Comment: `AND`, not `ADD`...

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @WesGray: Don't give up! You're going to love SQL once you get more familiar with it. Your question is a little unclear, so please update it with sample data and code in text. I attempted to provide an answer below based on my understanding of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're showing is a select statement

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerName, Region, Industry 
FROM sales
WHERE Region = 'West'
```

To add another criterion, use `and` as follows

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerName, Region, Industry 
FROM sales
WHERE Region = 'West'
 AND Industry = 'BusinessServices'
```

If you want to add a column to the table itself, proceed as follows

```
alter table sales add column Industry varchar
```